# Cydia package preinst/postinst can't reload launch daemon

Tags: ios, debian, jailbreak, cydia, launch-daemon

I'm writing an app for jailbroken iOS that includes both a UI application and a launch daemon. I set up the launch daemon as a subproject of the UI application project.

Everything's working perfectly, except that I can't get the package to unload and then reload the launch daemon as a part of the install process, or `chown` the launch daemon plist file to `root:wheel`.

In `mainproject/subproject/layout/DEBIAN/preinst` I have the following code:

```
#!/bin/sh
chown root:wheel /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plistname.plist
launchctl unload /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plistname.plist 2>&1 > /dev/null
```

and in `mainproject/subproject/layout/DEBIAN/postinst`:

```
#!/bin/sh
chown root /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plistname.plist
launchctl load /Library/LaunchDaemons/com.plistname.plist
```

If I uninstall the package and reinstall it, the plist is created, but it's owned by `502:staff`, and I'm not seeing the messages I see in `syslog` if I manually run `launchctl unload` and `launchctl load`.

Any idea what could be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out my problem was that the `preinst` and `postinst` scripts in the subproject weren't being run. I don't know if this is how debian packages are supposed to run or if it's just a bug in the way theos deals with subprojects, but I was able to resolve it by simply moving those commands to the `preinst` and `postinst` scripts for the main project.

It's not ideal since, logically, they belong with the subproject, but it works.